# Trying to center <img> tag and <p> tag within a <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a div tag and within that tag contains an img tag and a p tag. I wish to center these two elements on the same horizontal axis.

This is my code:

```css
.template-pill {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pill-icons {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div className="template-pill">
    <img className="pill-icons" src={healthy_logo} />
    <p> Healthy </p>
</div>
```

This is what I currently have:

[image]

But this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: Try `align-items: center` on `.template-pill`.

Answer (score 2):

justify content controls alignment  on the main axis. You should use align items: center as align items works for cross axis.

```
.template-pill {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

Answer (score 1):

Just add another css rule:

```
align-items: center;
```

in `.template-pill` and you would be done

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, just add some `padding` into the div and also dont forget to round borders with `border-radius`.

```css
    .template-pill {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 2px;
    }
    
    .pill-icons {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px solid green;     
    
    }
```

Comment: The padding won't align the two elements. You need to use `align-items: center` to align them. The padding will just push them down a bit but not align them.